# Derivative with respect to volume in physics

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Learning physics I found out that people sometimes write the following thing. I am not sure what it means and I hope that you can help me.

Assume that $f$ is sufficiently smooth function and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Consider sufficiently smooth and regular region of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which I will denote as $V$. Then, we define the number $P$ in the following way where $d^N x$ is the usual measure.

$$ P = \int \limits_V f(x) d^Nx $$

Then, in physics textbooks, one finds the following thing.

$$ \frac{dP}{dV} = f(x) $$

How is this defined and what does it mean? Intuitively, it seems like fundamental theorem of calculus but I am not sure.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't $dP = f\,dV$? That's the more typical way to write it in physics.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain, but it probably means that if you add a miniscule region to your $V$, the corresponding increase in $P$ divided by the volume of that region is (approximately) equal to the value of the function at an arbitrary point in that volume.

Comment: thanks! Do you think you know some references where such definition is made precise?

Comment: @DanielsKrimans If I did, I wouldn't have to guess.

Comment: arguable, but okay, thanks!